# In a Pandas MultiIndex Series , I want to remove the last element of the outer level of index , new series will have the same order as that of old

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
City        Year
Jallandhar  2011    23457
            2012    34523
Mohali      2011    22243
            2012    32239
Ludhiana    2011    32224
            2012    34343
Ambala      2011    33344
            2012    23999
dtype: int64
```

I want the output as:

```
City        Year
Jallandhar  2011    23457
            2012    34523
Mohali      2011    22243
            2012    32239
Ludhiana    2011    32224
            2012    34343
dtype: int64
```

This can not be achieved through slicing as slicing requires the index to be sorted, if sorted the output will not be in order. 
So what is the best way to get the output in same order as that of original series , while removing last element of the outer level of index.

Comment: I perhaps don't fully understand your comment about sorting. Do you mean that there could be rows with `Ambala` earlier in the DataFrame, not grouped with the final occurrence, and you would want to either retain them or also remove them? If so what behavior do you require?

Answer (score 1):

`drop` the last 'City'. You can refer to levels by names, but if you alway want the outermost level this will be `0`.

```
s = s.drop(s.index.get_level_values(0)[-1], level=0)
#City        Year
#Jallandhar  2011    23457
#            2012    34523
#Mohali      2011    22243
#            2012    32239
#Ludhiana    2011    32224
#            2012    34343
#dtype: int64
```